# how to know clock cycles, overall performance, etc... of program?

Tags: c, performance, matlab, debugging, ide

I have 3 different algorithms which all calculate the same stuff.
My goal is to compare all three algorithms, i.e. clock cycles, "how intensive it is for the processor", time needed to get the final result, the overall performance etc...

How can I see/get/analyze all of this information?

I am programming in Matlab and in C-language in code composer studio for an embedded system.

EDIT: memory usage/management would be usefull as well for the embedded system  especially

Comment: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/analyzing-your-programs-performance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can compare the size of your Output-files. Most times the bigger one is slower.

Get the exactly clock cycles is not easy. you must know how many clock cycles your Assembler command Needs and calculate it for your code.

If you are running it directly on your Hardware, you can toggle a port at the start and end Point and do a Timing measurement. (Regard there are may Interrupts, that can slow you down)

Answer (score 0):

For the MATLAB part, you should use the [timeit](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) function to evaluate performance. You can also use [profile](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) to inspect which, if any, parts of the code are causing bottlenecks.